# C# SqlBulkCopy miss a row

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using SqlBulkCopy to import data from excel and from another database into 2 different SQL tables.

Everything goes good until I managed that every time a row is missing in the target tables, either the source from the excel or from the other database.

Here is the code snippet for importing data from excel:

```
 public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath)
    {
        string ssqltable = "szip_IncomingAssetData";
        string myexceldataquery = "SELECT * FROM ["+ GetExcelSheetNames(excelFilePath)+"]";
        try
        {

            string sexcelconnectionstring = GetExcelConnectionString(excelFilePath);
            Logger.Log("Excel Connection String: " + sexcelconnectionstring, false);


            OpenDatabaseConnection(1, "ImportDataFromExcel");

            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);

            oledbconn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(hpamConnection)
            {
                DestinationTableName = ssqltable
            };

            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapID = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_AssetID"], "szip_IncomingAssetID");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapName = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetName"], "szip_IncomingAssetName");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapSerial = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetSerial"], "szip_IncomingAssetSerial");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapRI = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetRI"], "szip_IncomingAssetRI");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapModel = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetModel"],"szip_IncomingAssetModel");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapVendor = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetVendor"],"szip_IncomingAssetVendor");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapFRU = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetFirstRU"], "szip_IncomingAssetFirstRU");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapLRU = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetLastRU"], "szip_IncomingAssetLastRU");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapLocation = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetLocation"], "szip_IncomingAssetLocation");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapRack = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetRack"], "szip_IncomingAssetRack");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapStatus = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetStatus"], "szip_IncomingAssetStatus");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapConfig = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetConfig"], "szip_IncomingAssetConfig");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapIPDNS = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetIP_DNSname"], "szip_IncomingAssetIP_DNSname");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapArea = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetArea"], "szip_IncomingAssetArea");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapContact = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetContact"], "szip_IncomingAssetContact");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapExtension = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetExtension"], "szip_IncomingAssetExtension");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapHWType = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetHardwareType"], "szip_IncomingAssetHardwareType");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapConnections = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetCurrentConnections"], "szip_IncomingAssetCurrentConnections");
            SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapMaxConnections = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szip_IncomingAssetMaxConnections"], "szip_IncomingAssetMaxConnections");

            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapID);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapName);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapSerial);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapRI);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapModel);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapVendor);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapFRU);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapLRU);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapLocation);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapRack);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapStatus);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapConfig);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapIPDNS);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapArea);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapContact);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapExtension);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapHWType);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapConnections);
            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapMaxConnections);

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                  bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }
            dr.Close();
            oledbconn.Close();
            CloseDatabaseConnection(1, "ImportDataFromExcel");
            Logger.Log("Data Imported from Excel to Database", false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           Logger.Log("Cannot Read Excel File: " + e.Message.ToString(), true); 

        }
```

connection string is as follows:

```
private string GetExcelConnectionString(string excelfile)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
            ["Extended Properties"] = "'Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES'",
            ["Data Source"] = excelfile
        };


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
        {
            sb.Append(prop.Key);
            sb.Append('=');
            sb.Append(prop.Value);
            sb.Append(';');
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

In the case of the import from other database into my application database:

```
public void ImportSmartZoneAssetData()
    {

        SqlConnection hpamConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hpamConnectionString"]);
        SqlConnection smartZoneConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["szConnectionString"]);

        string sqlCommand = "select i.pa_deviceid as DeviceID, " +
                            "i.pa_displayname as DeviceName, " +
                            "j.PA_MATERIALIZEDSTRPATH as [Location], " +
                            "k.PA_CONTAINERTYPEID as ContainerTypeID, " +
                            "l.PA_CONTAINERTYPEDESCRIPTION as ContainerType, " +
                            "k.PA_DISPLAYNAME as ContainerName, " +
                            "i.PA_CONTAINERPOSITION as FirstRU, " +
                            "(select pa_assetvalue from PA_ASSETLIST where PA_PARENTID = i.PA_DEVICEID and PA_ASSETATTRIBUTEID = 24) as SerialNumber, " +
                            "(select pa_assetvalue from PA_ASSETLIST where PA_PARENTID = i.PA_DEVICEID and PA_ASSETATTRIBUTEID = 25) as BarCode " +
                            "from pa_device i " +
                            "left join PA_LOCATION j on i.pa_locationid = j.PA_LOCATIONID " +
                            "left join PA_CONTAINER k on i.PA_CONTAINERID = k.PA_CONTAINERID " +
                            "left join PA_CONTAINERTYPE l on k.PA_CONTAINERTYPEID = l.PA_CONTAINERTYPEID";

        string ssqltable = "szip_SmartZoneAssetData";

        SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(hpamConnection)
        {
            DestinationTableName = ssqltable
        };
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, smartZoneConnection);
        hpamConnection.Open();
        smartZoneConnection.Open();
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(myReader);
        }
        Logger.Log("Imported Records from SmartZone: " + GetRowsCopied(bulkcopy), false);
        myReader.Close();
        hpamConnection.Close();
        smartZoneConnection.Close();
        Logger.Log("Data Imported from SmartZone to Database", false);
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is something wrong in the code and the reason why I always loose one and only one record in both cases.

/**************************

Got rid of the "while (myReader.Read())" on both cases and now it works perfect. New code is:

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(myReader);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Log("Cannot Import SmartZone Device Data: " + e.Message, true);
        }
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: it is *probably* the "while (myReader.Read())" - this line of code does advance the reader to the first record....the bulk-copier *might* do the same *again*....resulting in first row missing.

Comment: Which row? The first or the last one?

Comment: from the excel looks like it is always the first row with data (actually the second since the first one contains the column names). On the SQL side it is hard to know, it is always a different one, I'm importing 40k+ records and the last test it was missing the position 10413.

Comment: @johannes.colmsee - That is exactly what happens (according to the docs) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets(v=vs.110).aspx - "Note that using WriteToServer modifies the state of the reader. The method will call Read until it returns false"

Comment: @Algis make this a self-answered question or delete the question. Not sure if it helps anyone except you in this specific case.

Comment: @Mafii - The question can certainly be cleaned up to only the relevant parts, but there is a more generally useful issue that others could also stumble into: DbDataReader.Read() was called before calling SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DbDataReader) causing data not to be copied by the SqlBulkCopy. I agree that the overly long sql statements and mappings that make up the bulk of the question are of no help to others.

Comment: @moreON I agree. It needs an answer instead of being solved inside the question body, tho.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is my first question here...Already create the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the while (myReader.Read()) was advancing one register.

I got rid of the "while (myReader.Read())" on both cases and now it works perfect. New code is:

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(myReader);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Log("Cannot Import SmartZone Device Data: " + e.Message, true);
    }
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: From the help..."You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!"  So I will do it tomorrow.